# Guard Malloc in Xcode 4.2. Where is it?

Tags: xcode, macos, xcode4.2

Where is it? Is there any other tool available from Xcode?

Thank you.

Comment: Xcode 4.2 is currently under NDA. Anybody who answers this question will be in breach of their contract with Apple. You should consider asking in Apple's developer forums — http://devforums.apple.com

Comment: Sorry, I don't remember agreeing to any NDA. Is it hidden in the developer agreement?

Comment: Yes, but slightly indirectly. The page on http://developer.apple.com from which you downloaded it will have had boilerplate text to the effect that "this is pre-release software and is considered Apple Confidential Information and is subject to the terms of your iOS Developer Program License Agreement." So Xcode 4.2 is covered by the confidential information clauses. Sorry for being a little pedantic about it, hopefully I managed to help nevertheless.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Now that the NDA no longer applies for xcode 4.2, here are the screenshots with the required steps.

[image: Product > edit scheme]

[image: Diagnostics > Enable Guard Malloc]

This should make it quicker for people still looking for Guard Malloc.

Answer (score 1):

As per my comment, it's not currently possible to comment on Xcode 4.2 in public.

However, if this is your first step into Xcode 4 from 3.2 then you may be having difficulty finding Guard Malloc in any event. As of 4.0 it's considered a diagnostic attribute of your scheme. So to enable it you should click the left part of pull down for your current scheme (the thing in the top bar to the right of the stop button), select 'edit scheme...', choose 'Run .app' in the left pane, then the 'Diagnostics' tab in the dialogue that appears on the right. You can enable or disable Guard Malloc in there.

That's true for 4.0 and 4.1. Hopefully it'll help you find your way in 4.2.

Comment: Thank you. It either was or wasn't true in xcode 4.2. I can't tell you. :P