# Can NSLog crash application?

Tags: iphone

I am new to iPhone SDK.I am printing each and every array in console.No matter how much data consume.and I note that some times my application is crashing.it gives me BAD_ACCESS and pointer showing on my NSLog line.I am confused can NSLog crash the application?
Here is my code :

```
for (int i = 0; i < [UserNeedListArray count]; i++) {
    EndUserNeed* aEndUser = [UserNeedListArray objectAtIndex:i];
    if ([appData.CurrentUser.userId isEqualToString:aEndUser.UserId]) {
        NSMutableArray* temp = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
        [temp addObject:aEndUser];
        NSLog(@"%@",temp);
        [arr_ShowMyOnly addObject:[temp objectAtIndex:0]];
        NSLog(@"%@",arr_ShowMyOnly);
        [temp removeAllObjects];
        [temp release];
        temp = nil;
    }
}
```

Please help me.Thanking you...

Comment: It's not the NSLog() itself but the variable you are trying to display what is making your app crash. I guess you are trying to log a variable that has been deallocated.

Try running your application with Instruments >> Zombies to get where you are deallocating the variable.

Comment: On which line exactly? Have you looked into debugging with Instruments (check for Zombies) - see also this answer to enable guard malloc and zombie objects. Gives you better debugging abilities in situations like this one: http://stackoverflow.com/a/8682294/397898

Comment: on this line : NSLog(@"%@",arr_ShowMyOnly);

Comment: What is arr_ShowMyOnly and where are you assigning to it

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Yes it can. when you do `NSLog(@"%@",temp);` it expects that `temp` is a type of NSString class.

In your case you should do  `NSLog(@"%@",[temp description]);` Almost all the classes have a description method that will return you an NSString object.

Comment: that is not right. `NSLog(@"%@", temp)` working fine. maybe it tries to send `description` message to object and show it's result, but it works.

Comment: Yes could be that it sends description to the object. But is not documented and after a while it could stop working. Look at what %@ expects https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Strings/Articles/formatSpecifiers.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40004265-SW1

Comment: from documentation, %@ assumes "Objective-C object, printed as the string returned by descriptionWithLocale: if available, or description otherwise". so, description will be send to an object automatically

Answer (score 5):

some more `NSLog()` example:

```
NSString *format = @"%s %d";    
NSLog(format, __FUNCTION__);
```

Would crash on a device and wouldn't crash on the simulator

Answer (score 0):

As the Ricard said, problem with your `arr_ShowMyOnly` variable , not with NSLog. Check where you retain and release it. Check if it was retained after creation< for example. By the way, you can add code of `arr_ShowMyOnly` initialilzation

Answer (score 0):

As arr_ShowMyOnly is allocated i assume, so do this:

```
  for (int i = 0; i < [UserNeedListArray count]; i++) 
  {
    EndUserNeed* aEndUser = [UserNeedListArray objectAtIndex:i];
    if ([appData.CurrentUser.userId isEqualToString:aEndUser.UserId]) 
    {
      [arr_ShowMyOnly addObject:aEndUser];
      NSLog(@"%@",arr_ShowMyOnly);
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this my be help you.

```
for (int i = 0; i < [UserNeedListArray count]; i++) {
        EndUserNeed* aEndUser = [UserNeedListArray objectAtIndex:i];
        if ([appData.CurrentUser.userId isEqualToString:aEndUser.UserId]) {
            NSMutableArray* temp = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
            [temp addObject:aEndUser];

            NSLog(@"%@",temp);
            if([temp count] >0)
            {
               [arr_ShowMyOnly addObject:[temp objectAtIndex:0]];
            }
            if([arr_ShowMyOnly count] >0)
            {
               NSLog(@"%@",arr_ShowMyOnly);
            }
            [temp removeAllObjects];
            [temp release];
            temp = nil;
        }
    }
```