# XCode 4.5 and static (singleton) class (C++)

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, static, singleton

I'm running into a weird issue with XCode 4.5, the one supporting the new iOS6.

In most of my apps, I make a State class as a singleton accessible from everywhere for convenience, but with latest XCode, it seems like after I set any non-static pointer member to some object, right after the assignment the value is back to NULL.

Even weirder is I only see the issue if I start a new project from scratch, not if I load an older project created with an earlier version of XCode. I looked at compiler settings, and everything looks the same. The issue only appears if I test on the actual device (iPhone4 running iOS6). The simulator does not show this problem.

Here's the relevent code :

State.h

```
class State
{
public:

    State();
    ~State();

     static State& Get();

private:
    static State * s_state;
```

State.mm

```
State* State::s_state = nil;

State& State::Get()
{
    if(s_state==nil)
        s_state = new State();
    return *(s_state);
}
```

Example usage assuming State has a non-static member Object * m_object :

```
void SomeClass::DoSomething()
{
    State::Get().SetObject( new Object() );

    // this will return null with newly created XCode 4.5 projects
    State::Get().GetObject();
```

** EDIT **
Regarding thread safety-ness, I'd like to know if the 2 cases below are considered "multi-threaded" scenarios.

I have one timer using display link for my opengl loop

```
[displayLink addToRunLoop:[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] forMode:NSDefaultRunLoopMode];
```

And I have one timer responsible for updating the game logic that I init this way

```
timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1.f/60.f target:self selector:@selector(timerUpdate) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
[[NSRunLoop mainRunLoop] addTimer:m_timer forMode:NSRunLoopCommonModes];
```

So if I call State::Get() from both these loops, is this considered a threaded scenario?

Thank you for your help.
- Marc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I found out what my issue was and thought I'd share with you all. Although it doesn't have anything to do with single/static classes, this kind of issue can be hard to debug.

In my State class, I had a member available only to a specific config :

```
#ifdef SOME_CONFIG
    int m_someValue;
#endif
```

The problem in this case was that at compile time, SOME_CONFIG was actually defined, but undefined elsewhere according to target conditionals etc, causing the variable to exist on the stack but never inited/used etc. Just having the variable in the header was causing the issue (even if I didn't make any call using it.)

Hope this can help someone out there.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Your code looks okay (although it is not threadsafe).  You don't post accessors, so I'll assume they are the standard type that actually get and set things.

Which means I can only guess but it's worth checking if the source of the problem is some corrupted memory that occurred earlier due to something like double delete.

Enable [guard malloc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7381210/guard-malloc-in-xcode-4-2-where-is-it) and try again.  You can also try valgrind.

About your edit, you should be okay as long as you are calling the addToLoop code from the main thread (you probably are calling it in some viewDidLoad or init code which is on the main thread), since both timer callbacks (timer and display link will be processed on the main loop).

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I'm going to take a look at guard malloc. I also edited the original question in regards to thread safety scenario I may be victim of in my case due to my app's structure.

Comment: I've tested doing game logic in the same loop as the opengl one, and it doesn't change anything. Guard Malloc alaso seems to only work on the sim, I tried it and didn't yield any interesting results. I'm still clueless on this one. If I set m_object as a static member of my State class, I don't have the issue.

Comment: You might want to try the static analyzer feature of xcode.  (just press and hold the play button).  It can track down memory issues as well.